# ERROR: IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF

Tags: sql, vb.net, linq

I am getting this error in my script:

> Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'GameMaster' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

Here is the code that is being executed:

```
        Dim db = New PlayerTestDataContextDataContext()

    If txtNewGM.Text = "" Then
        lbWarning.Text = "Please enter a name!"
    Else

        Dim GM As New GameMaster With {
            .GameMasterName = txtNewGM.Text}
        db.GameMasters.InsertOnSubmit(GM)
        db.SubmitChanges()

        Me.Close()

    End If
```

I have two tables in my database. Player, which has a PlayerID and PlayerName columns. And GameMasters, which has a GameMasterID, PlayerID, and GameMasterName with the PlayerID being a foriegn key from the player table. I have the primary keys Identity SPecification set you yes on each table(PlayerID for players and GameMasterID for GameMasters). What is causing this error. Ive searched around and found similiar problems but none have quite been the same thing...

Comment: While debugging can you see the value of `GM.GameMasterID`? If it has a value it will fail as it is PK with IDENTITY on that table.

Comment: I forgot how to view the values while debugging.

I used almost exactly the same code to create new Players and it works. The only thing different is the GameMaster class has the FK PlayerID in it. Could this be part of the reason for the error?

Comment: Scratch that. I did not fix my error.

Comment: The issue was related to the Foreign Key that wasnt getting a value assigned to it. I added an update for this FK in the code and it worked fine!

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you have an integer GameMasterID property declared on the GameMaster class.  Since integer properties are set to zero by default, when the insert occurs it is trying to set all of the properties, including the GameMasterID property.  So it tries to set the identity column to zero, which fails.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your data access routine is implicitly passing a non-NULL value when performing the insert (auto-prop with an implicit zero value, maybe).

The only time I've ever had that error is when I've tried to create a new record in a database table and have tried to set the identity field.  I think that's probably the only way you'll get it.

**EDIT:**

Almost certain an auto-prop is at play here.

Weird that the compiler will protect you from :-

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       int beef;
       string aLing = String.Format("{0}", beef);

    }
```

But not :-

```
 public int Beef { get; set; }

 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    string aLing = String.Format("{0}", Beef);
 }
```